# PayPal: Obtain a pay key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, paypal, payment-gateway

I'm using the following **HTML** for a *PayPal* lightbox to accept payments. Where can I get a pay key from for `value="insert_pay_key"`? Is the pay key the only aspect I need for this lightbox now to work? I'm new with integrating *PayPal* and I'm also too inexperienced to understand instructions on the *PayPal* developers website **[here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-embeddedPayment-curl-etc).**

```
<html>
   <head>
     <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
     <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay" target="PPDGFrame" class="standard">
       <label for="buy">Buy Now:</label>
       <input type="image" id="submitBtn" value="Pay with PayPal" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif">
       <input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="light">
       <input id="paykey" type="hidden" name="paykey" value="insert_pay_key">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      var embeddedPPFlow = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({trigger: 'submitBtn'});
    </script>
   </body>

</html>
```

At the moment, the lightbox will open and a message will appear saying "This transaction is invalid. Please return to the recipient's website and try again." I've also used a *PayPal* button which redirects to the *Paypal* website where I can successfully accept payments, however, I prefer the lightbox method as it doesn't take users away from my site page.If anyone could suggest how I can link this lightbox to my *PayPal* account I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: `Where can I get a pay key from for value="insert_pay_key"?` ... from paypal would be my suggestion - read ALL of the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/)

Comment: I'm having problems with the lightbox also, does work redirecting to another page, but lightbox already open with "This transaction is invalid. Please return to the recipient's website and try again." I used the same payKey that is generated with the normal payflow, just removed the redirect to paypal and opened my page with the form, but seems like thats not the way.